# Prove a function that is concave and convex is affine

Tags: functions, optimization

I am trying to prove the following: If a function $f$ is concave and convex, then it is affine.

Since $f$ is convex we have $f(\lambda x +(1-\lambda)y) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y))$ and $f(\lambda x +(1-\lambda)y) \geq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y)) $.  Thus we know $f(\lambda x +(1-\lambda)y) = \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y))$. This shows that $f$ is linear and hence it is affine.

Is this proof right? Could anyone tell me if there is another way to prove this? Thanks!

Comment: Two things: (i) You can't conclude that $f$ is linear. In general, it is not. (ii) You need to show that the last equation holds for all $\lambda$ not just $\lambda \in [0,1]$.

Comment: @copper.hat: I agree, although it's possible OP is using linear to mean "has no terms greater than linear".

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I did mean that f was a linear function not just that it doesn't have terms greater than linear.  Why can't we conclude that $f$ is linear?

Comment: Linear implies $f(tx) = t f(x)$, the function $f(t) =1 +t $ is affine but not linear.

Comment: $f(x)=a+bx$ is affine but not linear. $f(x)=bx$ is linear (and affine). You cannot conclude that $f$ is affine from your last equation since the statements hold $\forall \lambda\in[0,1]$ (which you are missing). Hence you can only conclude that $f$ is 'affine' between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: But since we have $f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) = \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y))$ doesn't that mean that f is linear? What would be the difference if we only had $ f(\lambda x ) = \lambda f(x) $, would that show $f$ is linear?

Comment: I gave an example above of a function that is affine but not linear.

Comment: Thanks I saw it as soon as I posted my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show that $f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda ) y) = \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda ) f(y)$ for all $\lambda$.

You have shown that this is true for $\lambda \in [0,1]$.

Assume $x \ne y$ (otherwise there is nothing to prove).

Suppose $\lambda >1$ and let $p=\lambda x + (1-\lambda ) y$.

Write $x = t p +(1-t) y$ and show that $\lambda = {1 \over t}$. In
particular, $t \in [0,1]$ and so 
$f(x) = t f(p) + (1-t) f(y)$. Hence $f(x) = {1 \over \lambda} f(p) + (1-{1 \over \lambda}) f(y)$ which gives
$f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda ) y) = \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda ) f(y)$.

The same sort of analysis applies for $\lambda <0$ (except we start with
$y = sx + (1-s) p$).

Answer (score 0):

Recently came across the same question, here's a detailed proof. Starting from
$$
f(\lambda x +(1-\lambda)y) = \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y)),\forall\lambda\in[0,1],\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n
$$
Let $y=0$, we have, still for $\lambda\in[0,1]$:
$$f(\lambda x)=\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda) f(0)\implies f(\lambda x)-f(0)=\lambda(f(x)-f(0))$$
let $g(x)=f(x)-f(0)$, we have, still, for $\lambda\in[0,1]$, $g(\lambda x)=\lambda g(x)$.

Now  we hope to prove this for any $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. First we extend $\lambda$ to all postive real numbers by noticing, if $y=\lambda x,\,\lambda>1$, we have
$$f(\lambda x)=\lambda(\frac{1}{\lambda} f(y))=\lambda(f(\frac{y}{\lambda}))=\lambda f(x)$$ since $\frac{1}{\lambda}<1$. Then since $g(x)=f(x)-f(0)$, which means $g$ is also both convex and concave, we have that
$$
g(\lambda x +(1-\lambda)y) = \lambda g(x) + (1-\lambda)g(y)),\forall\lambda\in[0,1],\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$$
This time we choose $t=\frac{1}{2}$ and $y=-x$, we have
$$\frac{1}{2}(g(-x)+g(x))=g(0)=f(0)-f(0)=0\implies g(x)=-g(-x),\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n$$
Then for any $\lambda\leq0$ we have
$$
g(\lambda x)=-g(-\lambda x)=-(-\lambda)g(x)=\lambda g(x)
$$
which extends the range of $\lambda$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Which means that $g$ is a linear functional on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and has the form $g(x)=a^Tx,a\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Thus $f$ has the form $f(x)=a^Tx+b$, which means it's an affine function.